# Find smallest subset of integers having a given sum

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, knapsack-problem

> Write a function that meets the specifications below:
>
> ```
> def find_combination(choices, total):
>
>     """
>     choices: a non-empty list of ints
>     total: a positive int
>
>     Returns result, a array of length len(choices) such that
>         * each element of result is 0 or 1
>         * sum(result*choices) == total
>         * sum(result) is as small as possible
>     In case of ties, returns any result that works.
>     If there is no result that gives the exact total, 
>     pick the one that gives sum(result*choices) closest 
>     to total without going over.
>    """
> ```

My solution uses a brute force approach, but it is very slow. How can I implement a faster solution?

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

    def find_combination(choices, total):
        bins = np.array(list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(choices))))
        combinations = [b for b in bins if sum(choices * b) == total]
        return (min(combinations, key=sum) if combinations else
                max([b for b in bins if sum(choices * b) < total], key=sum))
```

Comment: Some examples here:

If choices = [1,2,2,3] and total = 4 you should return either [0 1 1 0] or [1 0 0 1]
If choices = [1,1,3,5,3] and total = 5 you should return [0 0 0 1 0]
If choices = [1,1,1,9] and total = 4 you should return [1 1 1 0]

Comment: Looks like a Subset Sum problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). Try DP.

Comment: The docstring and parameters names don't match. This is misleading.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.